# html5 & javascript vertical range scroller fluid roullet effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new the StackExchange before posting my first question I have tried to search previous questions but I have unable to find my answer so I am posting my first question here .

Please excuse brevity or method of asking .

I am attaching an image of similar to what I am looking for, basically following are the list of things it needs to have or function as

1. Touch based vertical range scroller / selector
2. It will scroll up or down giving new range selection
3. When scroll up or down it continues to scroll with fluidity like a roulette wheel, means it does not just stop at next range number but it flow to few ahead and stops on some number eventually
4. The algorithm should eventually stop at some number in range not "null" value, i mean it should land at some value number not in-between numbers at empty space .

Image link of similar to what I am looking for

> [image]

I thank every one in advance for all the help.

Regards

Comment: I am not sure if you want someone from here to code it or need help in searching for a plugin, although in both cases you are on the wrong website since we help you fix your code not create your whole app :/